# WPF C# Preventing a background from resizing when loaded as a background in an inkCanvas

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, inkcanvas

After looking for the answer in both Microsoft documentation and forums, I am at a loss. I am loading a png image as a background for an inkCanvas (WPF) which works fine, however, it always resizes the image to fit in the canvas, despite the image size..

Here was my last attempt with no success:

```
            BitmapImage ii = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));
            Image img = new Image();

            img.Stretch = Stretch.None;
            img.Source = ii;
            InkCanvas1.Background = new ImageBrush(ii);
```

Here is what it looks like using Stretch.None and Stretch.Fill

[image]

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Can this be done?

Comment: So you want imageBrush to extend beyond ink canvas?

Comment: Not necessarily, I would like the image to be aspect ratio sized to either fit max width or max height and white space on the top or bottom of the canvas (depending on landscape or portrait image).

Comment: Can you post snapshot what it's like right now? And what's desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to set properties on an `Image` object that you're not using while ignoring the same settings on the `ImageBrush` that you are using. The `Image` in this case is just being thrown away and the `ImageBrush` just happens to be using the same source image. Set the `Stretch` property on the `ImageBrush` instead:

```
    BitmapImage ii = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));

    ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush(ii);
    imageBrush.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
    InkCanvas1.Background = imageBrush;
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you for making me feel like an idiot! :)